# how to fill the list<> using foreach?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, dropzone.js

i have a list  `List<string> img = new List<string>();` to store each path of the images in the list once the files uploaded it should img.Add(filename) to the list ,but it show error **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException** which means no filename stored in the list and the list is empty. anybody know what's going on ?

```
foreach (string s in Request.Files)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[s];
    int fileSizeInBytes = file.ContentLength;
    string fileName = file.FileName;// Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
    string fileExtension = "";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
    {
        fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
        string savedFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + fileExtension;
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/img/items/");
        string filename = path + savedFileName;
        file.SaveAs(filename);
        img.Add(filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line of code does the error occur at?  Set a breakpoint and find out.

Comment: when i use the list to assign it with var it show that's error

Comment: when you step through the code what is the value of file also looks like you should be using a for loop instead of a foreach take a look at what looks to be similar to what you are trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510007/c-sharp-getting-all-files-in-request-file

Comment: @MethodMan uploading multiple files work fine the issue is with filling the list with filename

Comment: so inside the if statement it's failing here `img.Add(filename);` ? also what is the value if `img` when you stop on that line.. can you show the full method so that we can see where `List<string> img = new List<string>();` is being declared...make sure it's declared at the Class level make it public static `'` is probably null and needs to be initialized.. sounds like a PostBack Issue

Comment: @MethodMan yes it declared at the same class level and it's public

Comment: @Methodman yes it's postback issue

Answer (score 2):

This is VERY suspicious: `foreach (string s in Request.Files)` and `Request.Files[s];`
I would guess you don't want to index "Request.Files" (whatever that is) by the string from "Request.Files" itself

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is undoubtedly related to the problem.  Maybe the OP can tell us what he is trying to do with Request.Files[s]

Comment: @EricJ. I tried to point the OP in the right direction using the information available in the question. In this case it's imho impossible to provide a complete answer in the sense of "doing this will fix it", so I posted this as an answer. Sorry if that was a mistake, I'm still a SO rookie, so any advice is welcome :)

Comment: Generally, if there's not enough information to answer the question it is best to add a comment telling them what else they need to clarify rather than taking a guess at an answer, or providing a partial answer.

Comment: @EricJ. OK, I will bear this in mind when answering in the future. Now do you think I should just delete this?

Comment: Why don't you wait a bit and see if the user clarifies the question well enough for a meaningful answer. I suspect you're on the right track, and your initial answer can be expanded to a good one if the question gets improved.

Comment: @EricJ. Right, that sound like a good plan :) Thanks for your help!